# why does inserting record into hive fails with FailedPredicateException?

Tags: hive

I'm trying to insert record into a table I created. But it fails with  FailedPredicateException(

I tried using alias for select statement, and then column names in sql, yet it fails with same error. What could be the issue?

```
create table sales_log(
trxn_uuid string,
unit_sold int,
unihprice decimal(13,4),
event_ts timestamp
)
stored as orc
location '/user/me/sales/sales_log';

insert into sales_log select 'axxx1', 2, 8,cast('2018-01-01 06:34:56.789' as timestamp);

hive> insert into sales_log select 'axxx1', 2, 8,cast('2018-01-01 06:34:56.789' as timestamp);
FailedPredicateException(regularBody,{$s.tree.getChild(1) !=null}?)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.regularBody(HiveParser.java:43166)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.queryStatementExpressionBody(HiveParser.java:42341)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.queryStatementExpression(HiveParser.java:42211)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.execStatement(HiveParser.java:1681)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.statement(HiveParser.java:1152)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:211)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:171)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:438)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:321)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileInternal(Driver.java:1224)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1265)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1161)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1151)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:217)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:169)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:380)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:740)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:685)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:625)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:233)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:148)
FAILED: ParseException line 1:87 Failed to recognize predicate '<EOF>'. Failed rule: 'regularBody' in statement
```

Comment: which hive version?

Comment: fixed only in 1.31 / 2.0 https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-12200

Comment: version is 1.2.

Comment: Hi @Shivam your answer was good! `insert into table sales_log select * from (
    select 'axxx1', 2, 8,cast('2018-01-01 06:34:56.789' as timestamp)
) a;` ,  if you post again I help you to explain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Known issue, fixed in Hive 1.3.1/2.0.

You can’t use `insert as select` without `from` clause in earlier versions. Rewrite your query using insert `into ... values ...` or upgrade to latest Hive version.