# How to insert by select?

Tags: hive, hiveql

There is a `CREATE TABLE t1 (a int, b int, x string)`, and  the instruction `SELECT 1 a, 2 b, 'hello' x;` is valid, so I expected that it is not an error:

```sql
INSERT INTO my_db.t1 SELECT 1 a, 2 b, 'hello' x;
-- OR
INSERT INTO my_db.t1 SELECT a, b, x FROM t2;
```

**Why** it is an error? ... Or it is a bug?

*Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:40 Failed to recognize predicate ''. Failed rule: 'regularBody' in statement (state=42000,code=40000)*

---

NOTES.

Also tested `INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE my_db.t1  PARTITION(x) SELECT ...` when used *t* with partition... but same error.

Seems [why does inserting record into hive fails with FailedPredicateException?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51880673/287948) but in my case it not works also with SELECT FROM.

Hive version seems **1.2**... `hive --version`  say

*2021-03-26 09:22:44,840 DEBUG [main] util.HiveVersionInfo: version: @org.apache.hive.common.HiveVersionAnnotation(version=1.2.1000.2.6.4.0-91, shortVersion=1.2.1000, revision=87f2bc04724e559819902a574e78b2beeaf9f541, branch=(detached from 87f2bc0), user=jenkins, date=Thu Jan 4 10:47:01 UTC 2018, url=git://ctr-e134-1499953498516-209689-01-000004.hwx.site/grid/0/jenkins/workspace/HDP-parallel-centos7/SOURCES/hive, srcChecksum=73af1d20b2f8a15f36ac132297e70386)
Hive 1.2.1000.2.6.4.0-91
Subversion git://ctr-e134-1499953498516-209689-01-000004.hwx.site/grid/0/jenkins/workspace/HDP-parallel-centos7/SOURCES/hive -r 87f2bc04724e559819902a574e78b2beeaf9f541
Compiled by jenkins on Thu Jan 4 10:47:01 UTC 2018
From source with checksum 73af1d20b2f8a15f36ac132297e70386
2021-03-26 09:22:45,177 DEBUG [Thread-0] util.ShutdownHookManager: ShutdownHookManger complete shutdown.*

Comment: Strange, what is your hive version?

Comment: Hi @KoushikRoy, seems version 1.2, I edited, see Notes.

Comment: I am using 2.x so not sure whats happening. Can you check if you can load into a non-partitioned table ? And is this happening for all tables or something specific? If this is first time and happening for all tables and it used to work, then obviously something changed - configuration/file system etc.